# Reactjs, something is wrong in my script but I don't know what

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working in react and I have here icon and I need to make this icon a hover state, like in css but I need to do this in react app, Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var FontIcon = React.createClass({

getInitialState: () => {
    return {
        hover: false,
    };
},

render(){

    var _props = this.props,
    iconStyle = {
        'font-size': _props.size,
        cursor: "default"
    }

    function hoverOn(){
        this.setState({
            hover: true
        });
    }

    function hoverOff(){
        this.setState({
            hover: false
        });
    }

    if (this.state.hover) {
        iconStyle.color = _props.hoverColor;
    } else {
        iconStyle.color = _props.color;
    }

    return(
            <i className="material-icons" style={iconStyle} onmouseenter={this.hoverOn} onmouseleave={this.hoverOff} >{_props.className}</i>
    );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <FontIcon className="account_circle" size="100" color="blue" hoverColor="red" />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And I don't know what is wrong :/ Thanks for help

Comment: Don't declare functions inside `render`. They should be on the same level as `render`.

Comment: @FabianSchultz, but now it's giving me error like this: ERROR in ./app.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /my path/ Unexpected token, expected , (12:1)

  10 |  }
  11 |
> 12 |  function hoverOn(){
     |  ^
  13 |      this.setState({
  14 |          hover: true
  15 |      });

Comment: Lose the `function` in the front.

Comment: yeah, basically it's giving me error where first of that functions start

Comment: Yep, you don't need to declare it as a `function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do not use setState in render() ! 
After, beware that React events are all written in CamelCase because this is just javascript. Try something like this:

```
var FontIcon = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            hover: false,
        };
    },
    hoverOff() {
        this.setState({
            hover: false
        });
    },
    hoverOn() {
        this.setState({
            hover: true
        });
    },
    render() {
        var _props = this.props;
        var iconStyle = {
            'font-size': _props.size,
            cursor: "default"
        };

        if (this.state.hover) {
            iconStyle.color = _props.hoverColor;
        } else {
            iconStyle.color = _props.color;
        }

        return(
            <i className="material-icons" 
               style={iconStyle} 
               onMouseEnter={this.hoverOn} 
               onMouseLeave={this.hoverOff} >
                {_props.className}
            </i>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: but now, there is nothing on the screen

Comment: Just edited my code...

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's all working, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't declare functions inside `render`. `Render` function called very often, so, every time browser will create new function and delete old functions from memory.
2. You need to use onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave property: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events

So, result code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var FontIcon = React.createClass({

getInitialState: () => {
    return {
        hover: false,
    };
},

hoverOn() {
   this.setState({
       hover: true
   });
},

hoverOff() {
   this.setState({
       hover: false
   });
},

render() {
    var _props = this.props,
    iconStyle = {
        'font-size': _props.size,
        cursor: "default"
    }

    if (this.state.hover) {
        iconStyle.color = _props.hoverColor;
    } else {
        iconStyle.color = _props.color;
    }

    return(
            <i className="material-icons" 
               style={iconStyle} 
               onMouseEnter={this.hoverOn} 
               onMouseLeave={this.hoverOff}>           
                    {_props.className}
            </i>
    );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <FontIcon className="account_circle" size="100" color="blue" hoverColor="red" />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Don't need to bind here...this is not es6 classes and "this" is autobinded when using React.createClass

Comment: @Timur Bilalov, thanks for answering, but it's still not working

Comment: Seb, thanks for explaining. Karol, I found the error. You need to use onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave, not onmouseenter and onmouseleave as a property for component.

Comment: I see it now, thanks a lot